# Dispatch an action onChange input

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to dispatch an action on input onChange. The `searchQuery()` get's called but doesn't dispatch the action.

Here is the component with the input tag

```
const SearchBar = () => 
  <Card>
    <div className={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
      <div className={styles.field}>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event)=> searchQuery(event.target.value)} placeholder="Search for items or sellers" />
      </div>
      <Button className={styles.searchButton}>
        Search
      </Button>
    </div>
  </Card>

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {

  }
} 

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatch
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

The `searchQueryRequest()` request does not get dispatched. The `searchQuery()` function works though.

```
export const SEARCH_QUERY_REQUEST = 'SEARCH_QUERY_REQUEST'
function searchQueryRequest(query) {
  console.log(query) // doesn't get called
  return { type: SEARCH_QUERY_REQUEST, query }
}

export function searchQuery(query) {
  console.log(query) // works till here
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(searchQueryRequest(query))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dispatch the `searchQuery()` function as well.

```
const SearchBar = ({ searchQuery }) => 
  <Card>
    <div className={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
      <div className={styles.field}>
        <input type="text" onChange={(event)=> searchQuery(event.target.value)} placeholder="Search for items or sellers" />
      </div>
      <Button className={styles.searchButton}>
        Search
      </Button>
    </div>
  </Card>

const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {

  }
} 

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    searchQuery: (val) => dispatch(searchQuery(val))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Comment: Glad I could help.